# Javascript hoisting and global scope declaration

Tags: javascript

In javascript, compilation phase find and associate all declarations with their appropriate scopes.

#### CASE1

```
a = 2;
console.log(a);
```

If not used in strict mode the snippet is assumed to be actually processed as:

```
var a;
a = 2;
console.log(a);
```

**Output: 2**

#### CASE2

if the declaration happens below console.log()

```
  console.log(a); 
  var a = 2;
```

Here at line 1: compiler will check for the declaration of a in its scope if not found, the global scope will assign one and the same code will be assumed again same as

```
   var a; 
   console.log(a);
   a = 2;
```

**Output : undefined** // as no value is assigned while interpreter read console

#### CASE3

```
 console.log(a); 
 a = 2;
```

**Output: RefErr**

Why this throws reference error and not undefined?

Comment: [Only declarations are hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#Only_declarations_are_hoisted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully look at your first two cases, you are always declaring the variable `a`, and in JavaScript only the declarations are hoisted.

That being said, in your `Case 3`, variable `a` is never declared, hence, hoisting is not possible here. With that, there is no variable by the name `a` in the scope, and hence, `ReferenceError`.

If you look at the description of [ReferenceError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError), it reads:

> The ReferenceError object represents an error when a non-existent variable is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit globals **do not** imply a `var` statement. There is no hoisting of them.